# On Windows 7, can I customize it so that when I click an app, all 3 windows of it re-open?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have an app (such as Command Prompt), and there are 3 windows open for it (3 instance of the app).

If I click on it on the task bar, it pops out 3 windows and let me choose which one to reopen.  Can it be configured like the Mac so that when I click on it, all 3 will re-open?

Answer (score 4):

There's two ways I know of to do something along these lines:

1. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left click the application's taskbar icon. Each click will open another of the application instances. It doesn't open them all at once but if you click enough times they will all reappear.
2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click the application's taskbar icon, then select Restore all windows.

   [image: Right click taskbar icon with shift held down]